# SparkPi example algorithm - why open disc

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark

I'm getting started with spark and trying to follow SparkPi example (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala)

I can't understand why the disk used in the algorithm is open. Shouldn't we use x*x + y*y <= 1 instead?

Here's a very simple comparison code (https://gist.github.com/mrydzy/1cf0e5c316ef9d6fbd91426b91f1969f) and x*x + y*y <= 1 seems to be performing slightly better - but since the difference is really small, I'll appreciate confirmation or explanation.

Comment: Let's say that it's an approximation and an example. It was not made to be optimized rather than just an example but you are right.

Comment: The boundary is the circle has measure 0, so mathematically it makes no difference. As for the algorithm, whatever the difference (and it should be tiny), it is almost certainly just a consequence of the use of finite precision math.